# Rendering all the world universities in a react input field - stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component for an input to select a university. We have more than 9000 options covering all the universities in the world. I have listed only 4 in this example.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Input } from "reactstrap";

class Universities extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            Universities : [
                <option value= "1 December University of Alba Iulia">1 December University of Alba Iulia</option>
                ,<option value= "2nd Military Medical University">2nd Military Medical University</option>
                ,<option value= "3rd Military Medical University">3rd Military Medical University</option>
                ,<option value= "4th Military Medical University">4th Military Medical University</option>

            ]
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Input
                type="select">
                    
                    {this.state.Universities}
                </Input>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Universities;
```

If I add all the 9000+ options (***even if they are assigned to a variable in the state or imported from a universities.js file***), I get the error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at shouldFilterFiber
```

What is the best solution to add more than 9000 options to an input of type select to solve this problem?

Comment: I think 9000+ options in one `select` is bad UX as it will cause tremendous lag when the user opens it. Maybe you should split them into countries and have 2 `select`s one for country and one for universities, that will reduce the amount of options you have to show at one time

Comment: Still we tried to implement this as a search select for UX concerns as you've said but we still get the same error.

Comment: We can't do much for you when you post working code - we need to see exactly what you're doing that is causing the error.  Also,  perhaps a `datalist` html element would be a more suitable for such a large list as it only renders options based on user search string.

Comment: The error is happening at `shouldFilterFiber` - that's where your issue is. I googled it and got a hit for reactDevTools. If it's not one of your functions, then that might be a good place to look. Here's a JS fiddle of react quite happily rendering 9000 options: [https://jsfiddle.net/hnvkd03L/](https://jsfiddle.net/hnvkd03L/).

Answer (score 0):

The call stacks refers to functions that are called so the problem shouldn't exactly be the 9000+ options, but how the function `shouldFilterFiber` works. Maybe it does too much recursion or calls too many other functions without executing them. I suppose this would work with only 4 options, like the code you show here. So  that tells me that the function calls functions based on the amount of input and then does recursion through all the input.

This is just theory, I sadly have no clue about js. Maybe someone else can give you a more explicit solution